# Test Note in TestFlight

Tags: ios, testing, testflight

[image]

i want to know where i can give some description to test notes in TestFlight. Because whats in the test information build only shows for the most recent build. And who can change the test note for the build? is it the app owner or the tester?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access right, then you can login into https://appstoreconnect.apple.com, you can edit the test note in the platform, for the App which you have access right.

Comment: but where is it really? i didn't find the test note tab or field in the app store connect.

Answer (score 1):

Select TestFlight tab > select your build and you will see Test Details box

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issues since years.

For apps which have one language (so the primary language), English (U.S.), it works as expected.
But for apps which have one language, like German, the  latest build view displays the release notes, but notes the previous build views (the one shared in the first post).